# Passing multiple subviews to a view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have created a Swift Package that creates multiple PageTabViews from an array of content that is passed to it:

```
import SwiftUI

public struct WhatsNewView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: [Content]
    
    public init(content: [Content]){
        self.content = content
    }
        
    public var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0..<content.count, id: \.self) { pageNum in
                WhatsNewPage(content: content[pageNum], pageNum: pageNum + 1, totalPages: content.count)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

When I call it I want to pass in any kind of simple or complex view to fill each page. Right now, I can pass in an array of simple text views like so:

```
import SwiftUI
import WhatsNew

@main
struct mFood_Vendor: App {
    @State var showWhatsNew = false
    let whatsNew = WhatsNew()

    var page1 = Text("Hello World")

    var page2 = Text("Goodbye World")

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showWhatsNew, content: {
                let content = [page1, page2]
                WhatsNewView(content: content)
            })
            .onAppear(perform: {
                whatsNew.checkForUpdate(showWhatsNew: $showWhatsNew)
            })

        }
    }
}
```

I want page1 and page2 to be whatever content a person wants to see on the What's New pages. But if I change those vars to anything different, like a text and an Image, I get a "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression" error.

Ideally, I would like to be able to pass in something like:

```
struct page1: View {
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        Text("something")
        Image("plus")
       }
     }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `AnyView` to get what you want. In that case your code would become:

```
public struct WhatsNewView: View {

    let content: [AnyView]

    public init(content: [AnyView]){
        self.content = content
    }

    public var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0..<content.count, id: \.self) { pageNum in
                WhatsNewPage(content: content[pageNum], pageNum: pageNum + 1, totalPages: content.count)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

And, as an example of usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let view1 = AnyView(Text("Hello World"))
        let view2 = AnyView(Image(systemName: "star.fill"))
        return WhatsNewView(content: [view1, view2])
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I've just found out that `TabView` can be built out of a `TupleView`. This means that, *depending on your needs*, you can write something like this (which would be great because it doesn't force your Swift Package users to wrap all the views inside `AnyView`):

```
import SwiftUI

public struct WhatsNewView<Content: View>: View {
    private let content: Content

    public init(@ViewBuilder contentProvider: () -> Content){
        content = contentProvider()
    }

    public var body: some View {
        TabView {
            content
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WhatsNewView {
            Text("Hello World")
            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
            Color.red
            VStack {
                Text("Text1")
                Text("Text2")
                Text("Text3")
            }
            Button("Tap Me") {
                print("Tapped")
            }
            Group {
                Text("Group1")
                Text("Group2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if I leave WhatsNewView alone, I can just do the following:

```
struct mFood_Vendor: App {
    @State var showWhatsNew = false
    let whatsNew = WhatsNew()

    var page1: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            Text("Here is a list of new features:")
            Text("Hello World")
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
    }

    var page2: some View {
        Text("Goodbye World")
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showWhatsNew, content: {
                let content = [AnyView(page1), AnyView(page2)]
                WhatsNewView (content: content)
            })
            .onAppear(perform: {
                whatsNew.checkForUpdate(showWhatsNew: $showWhatsNew)
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Basically just wrap each content page in AnyView.

Comment: Take a look at my EDIT, I think it might be useful to you.

Comment: Sweet! I really like that solution! Thanks.