# How to pass in content for TabView through a function

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview, viewbuilder

I am trying to build a reusable onboarding pager overlay. So I want to pass in different "slides" into the pager `TabView` based on a variable `IntroType`. But since `TabView` takes content plainly without any container, what would be the return type for that?

This is how I wish it worked:

```
struct IntroViewTabPageTest: View {
    // MARK: Variables
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State var activeSlide: Int = 0
    var introType: IntroType
    
    // MARK: UI
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Color.darkGalaxy
            
            TabView(selection: $activeSlide) {
                getContentBasedOnType() // <---- Content here
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Functions
    private func getContentBasedOnType() -> some View {
        switch (introType) {
        case .Main:
            return introContentMain
        case .SA:
            return introContentSA
        case .Journey:
            return introContentJourney
        }
    }
}

// Static content blocks for each type
extension IntroViewTabPageTest {

    // ----> Of course everywhere errors here, "some View" is not the right return type;
    // But what is it?

    private var introContentMain: some View {
        MainIntroSlide1()
        TextSlide(headline: "Headline", text: "Text")
    }
    
    private var introContentSA: some View {
        TextSlide(headline: "Headline", text: "Text")
        TextSlide(headline: "Headline2", text: "Text2")
        TextSlide(headline: "Headline3", text: "Text3")
    }
    
    private var introContentJourney: some View {
        TextSlide(headline: "Headline", text: "Text")
    }
}

enum IntroType: String {
    case Main, SA, Journey
}

struct IntroViewTabPageTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        IntroViewTabPageTest(isPresented: .constant(true), introType: .Main)
    }
}
```

---

An alternative would be to have each variable in the extension return a whole `TabView`, but that's very ugly and I haven't figured it out fully either, still getting some other error with that route.

I assume that there must be **some** way to do this and I just don't know the available tools of SwiftUI well enough yet. I can imagine a function with a @ViewBuilder wrapper could be of use here, but I don't fully understand the logic behind it so far.

The closest I've come was using an array of AnyView() downcasts of the slides, but that made using a ForEach hard and erased the types.

Comment: Best approach is opinion based and out of scope in SO read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 
But looking at the code I would say that maybe reconsidering your approach to react to data vs thinking about passing views might help you,  something like VIPER architecture and/or protocols. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982225/im-trying-to-implement-a-view-stack-in-swiftui-and-my-state-objects-are-being/69996884#69996884) too not the same, you might get an idea on what will work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the content in like this:

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct IntroViewTabPageTest<Content: View>: View {
  
      let content: Content
  
      init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
      }
  
      var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
          Color.gray
      
          TabView() {
            self.content
          }
          .tabViewStyle(.page)
          .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
        }
      }
  
    }

    struct IntroViewTabPageTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
      static var previews: some View {
        Group {
      
          IntroViewTabPageTest {
            Text("hello 1")
            Text("hello 2")
          }
      
          IntroViewTabPageTest {
            Rectangle()
              .fill(Color.green)
              .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
          }
      
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Ahh, I've seen this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64977022/1972372) but did not understand where "Content" came from. Does this line `IntroViewTabPageTest<Content: View>: View` mean you're simply specifying something like a typealias for `View` so that you can then use `Content` as a type?

Comment: Anyway, thank you a lot. This is exactly what I've been looking for. Unfortunately made me realize that with this the structure is not as good as expected and I might have to write my code differently.

Answer (score 3):

With @Chris' help I made it work like following:

```
import SwiftUI


struct IntroView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var introType: IntroType

    var body: some View {
        if (introType == .Main) {
            getContentMain()
        }
        else if (introType == .SA) {
            getContentSA()
        }
        else if (introType == .Journey) {
            getContentJourney()
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct IntroTabView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State var activeSlide: Int = 0
    let slideAmount: Int
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, slideAmount: Int, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.slideAmount = slideAmount
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Color.darkGalaxy
            
            TabView(selection: $activeSlide) {
                self.content
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            
            // Buttons
            HStack { ... }
            .padding(16)
        }
    }
}

// Static content blocks for each type
fileprivate extension IntroView {
    private func getContentMain() -> some View {
        IntroTabView(isPresented: $isPresented, slideAmount: 3) {
            MainIntroSlide1().tag(0)
            TextSlide(headline: "Headline", text: "Text").tag(1)
            TextSlide(headline: "Headline2", text: "Text2").tag(2)
        }
    }
    
    private func getContentSA() -> some View {
        IntroTabView(isPresented: $isPresented, slideAmount: 2) {
            TextSlide(headline: "Headline", text: "Text").tag(0)
            TextSlide(headline: "Headline2", text: "Text2").tag(1)
        }
    }
    
    private func getContentJourney() -> some View {
        IntroTabView(isPresented: $isPresented, slideAmount: 1) {
            TextSlide(headline: "Headline", text: "Text").tag(0)
        }
    }
}

enum IntroType: String {
    case Main, SA, Journey
}

struct IntroView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        IntroView(isPresented: .constant(true), introType: .Main)
    }
}
```

Resulting in this nice view:
[image]